# How to install jboss fuse 6.3 on intellij

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

Hi i am trying to configure the jboss fuse 6.3 server with intellij, but when selecting the folder of my server it says it cannot find a valid jboss directory[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSOxx.png)

In ret hat code studio ready it works fine but i need to lift it in the intellij

Answer (score 2):

I think that in IntelliJ, the wizard that you are using is for Jboss EAP. Given the name of path to Jboss Fuse, you are using the JBoss Fuse version based on Karaf.

So depending on the constraints of you project, either you need to look for a Karaf Application server in IntelliJ if it is provided; or you need to pick a JBoss EAP server and then install JBoss Fuse in this instance using the JBoss Fuse on EAp installer. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/installation_on_jboss_eap/installing_red_hat_jboss_fuse_on_eap

Please note that 6.3 version is quite old. The latest version is 7.6.0 https://access.redhat.com/announcements/4925931

regards,